# Show that all the real intervals $(a,b),(p,q],[c,d),[x,y]$ have the same cardinality.

Tags: real-analysis

Show that all the real intervals $(a,b),(p,q],[c,d),[x,y]$ have the same cardinality.

I knew that the above statement is true, indeed. But the problem is in no books, I found a proof of this statement. Neither did I find any mention of this (till now). From that time, I always wanted to prove this interesting fact. However, due to lack of time, I never made it up until now.

But today, I finally tried to finish the unfinished buisness :

*Here, we try to show that all (bounded) real intervals have the same cardinality.*

We first try to prove that $(0,1)$ and $(a,b)$ have the same cardinality. We try to construct a bijection, between the two intervals.

We try to map the interval $(0,1)$ to $(0,b-a)$ by using the transformation $t\to (b-a)t.$ After this, we map the interval $(0,b-a)$ to  $(a,b)$ using the transfformation $t\to t+a.$ We note that all these transformations are bijections and so, their composition is a bijection as well. Hence, $f:(0,1)\to (a,b)$ is a  bijection such that $f(x)=(b-a)x+a.$

- *This proves that all the open intervals have the same cardinality.*

Similarly, we may prove, that   $\sigma:[0,1]\to [a,b]$ is a  bijection such that $\sigma(x)=(b-a)x+a.$

- *This proves that all the closed intervals have the same cardinality.*

Proceding in the like manner,

We also conclude, that $f_1:[0,1)\to [a,b)$ is a  bijection such that $f_1(x)=(b-a)x+a.$

- *This proves that all the intervals of the form $[a,b)$ have the same cardinality,* and

$f_2:(0,1]\to (a,b]$ is a  bijection such that $f_2(x)=(b-a)x+a.$

- *This proves that all the  intervals  of the form $[a,b)$ have the same cardinality.*

Now, we try to prove that $(0,1)$ has the same cardinality has $[0,1].$

We first  show that there exists an injection between  $(0,1)$ and  $[0,1].$

We consider the mapping, $f:(0,1)\to [0,1]$ defined as $f(x)=x.$ We note that $f$ is an injection.

Next, we consider the mapping $g:[0,1]\to (0,1)$ defined as $g(x)=\frac{(x+1)}{3}.$ We note that $g $is an injection as well.

- *Using Schröder-Bernstein Theorem, we can conclude that $(0,1)$ has the same cardinality as $[0,1].$*

*Till now, we have proved that  all the open and closed intervals have the same cardinality.*

We consider the mapping  $h:[0,1]\to (0,1]$ and $\phi:[0,1]\to [0,1)$ defined via $h(x)=\phi(x)=\frac{x+1}{3}.$ We observe that $h$ and $\phi$ are injections.

Also, the mappings, $h_1:(0,1]\to [0,1]$ and $\phi_1: [0,1)\to [0,1]$ defined by $h_1(x)=x$ and $\phi_1(x)=x$ are injections.

- *Using  Schröder-Bernstein Theorem, we can conclude that $[0,1)$ and $(0,1]$ has the same cardinality as $[0,1].$*

Compiling all the informations till now, we can say,
$(0,1),[0,1),(0,1]$ has the same cardinality as $[0,1].$

This means that all *bounded real intervals* has the same cardinality, as bijections are simply *equivalence relations.*

---

This was my little attempt to prove this general piece of information. I tried various ways to prove this for many a days now, but never manage to do it completely.

If I am not really mistaken, then *(surprisingly!)* this is till now not posted here as well. I want to present this work to this community and want precise judgements whether my work is at all valid ? If there are any mistakes, please do let me know.

Finally, is there any way I can improve the proof?

Comment: $(p,q]=\cup_n(p,q_n)$ where $q_n$ is a sequence of rational tending to $q$. Then keeping in mind that $\mathbb Q$ is countable and the countable union of sets having same cardinality has the same cardinality you finish. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: @Piquito But what do you think about my method? Is it valid?

Comment: Dear friend, you are surely right but your statement in not enough relevant because well known for almost everyone.

Comment: @Piquito You understand me wrong, buddy. The thing is, yes, its known to most but a formal proof of this is surely lacking. Even it's not posted here earlier and that surely comes below the belt and considered adding to the repository

Comment: This actually has been asked many times. Search something along the lines of "explicit bijection between (0,1) and [0,1]." If you want to keep thinking about the problem, try to give an explicit bijection.

Comment: @AndrewZhang I surely don't get what you mean by an "explicit bijection". This is because, as far as bijections are concerned, everything is either explicit or not explicit. If it's not explicit then it's not a bijection at all. I think the bijections I have written down, is completely explicit/precise if I understand you correctly, though. So, it doesn't really make sense, unless you consider clarifying things...

Comment: You've shown that $(0,1)\sim [0,1]$, namely, there exists a bijection between these two sets. An explicit bijection would be to actually give an example of one. In another vein, it is very easy to show there must be transcendental numbers, there are only countably many algebraic numbers and uncountably many reals. Actually exhibiting a transcendental number is much harder.

Comment: Proof looks fine to me. Could be made a little more succinct.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you, for your kind clarification. I would be grateful, if you consider adding your valuable insights as an answer, if you're interested in it. I will be mire than glad to accept it and I bet it will come to use, as a valuable thread to future users like me, who might very well stumble upon this question, in their mathematical journey as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof looks correct.

A comment about the proof: Proofs are a social process, the goal to convince the audience that the statement is true. Your proof is correct but more suited to machine verification that a human reader.

I think this is a normal part of learning the proof writing process. If one can make a digestible generalisation then the proof will be easier for a human reader.

This is a very terse in order to make a point, but I would lean towards writing something along the lines of:

The same formula shows that $[a,b] \sim [0,1]$, etc, and the inclusion map from any of the intervals to $[0,1]$ is injection, hence the cardinality of $[0,1]$ is greater than or equal to any of the intervals. The map $x \mapsto {1 \over 3}(1+x)$ maps $[0,1]$ injectively into any of the intervals, hence by Schröder-Bernstein, the cardinalities are equal.

Comment: Thanks a ton, for your apt and immensely useful answer!